# Azure AD B2C - Let Parent reset password of Child account

Tags: reactjs, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Till now, in our react application, we have used our own server to authenticate and authorize users. As our application is scaling and we have to integrate it with other apps, we require the OAuth 2.0 flow for authorization and authentication.

Azure AD B2C helps with sign-up, sign-in, and other basic processes, but we have a functionality where a parent account has access to change the password of their child account.

Is it possible to do this with Azure AD B2C?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will have to implement the authorization logic yourself.
Essentially, you'll grant your back-end application access to reset any users' password through the Graph API.
Then in your back-end, when a user is trying to reset a user's password, you check that they are the parent account (+ any other authorization rules).

Comment: Is there any documentation I can refer to?

Comment: Your app would need to call the update user endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. The property you are looking for is passwordProfile.